# Candy machine team group allocation configuration

Tags: candy-machine-v3

What is the best way to implement some « team allocation » in Candy Machine v3 (sugar)?

Maybe a « group » with 0 sol mint price? How do I specify allowed addresses in such a group though?

Answer (score 0):

By "Team Allocation" I am assuming you are suggesting some amount of mints are allocated to your the team. To do this, you'd probably want a [Guard Group](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/guard-groups) and a combination of multiple Candy Guards:

- [Allow List](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/allow-list) to specify the wallets that can mint
- [Mint Limit](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/mint-limit) to specify how many each of those wallets can mint
- [Start Date](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/start-date) and [End Date](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/end-date) to determine when those users can mint

You could alternatively do something like [Token Burn](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/token-burn) but this would require distributing WL tokens and could be transferable.

Here's a list of [All Guards](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/candy-guards).

Using JS/Umi--that'd be something like:

```
import { some, sol, dateTime } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { getMerkleRoot } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";

const allowList = [
  "Ur1CbWSGsXCdedknRbJsEk7urwAvu1uddmQv51nAnXB",
  "GjwcWFQYzemBtpUoN5fMAP2FZviTtMRWCmrppGuTthJS",
  "AT8nPwujHAD14cLojTcB1qdBzA1VXnT6LVGuUd6Y73Cy",
];

const candyGuard = await fetchCandyGuard(umi, candyMachine.mintAuthority);
await updateCandyGuard(umi, {
  candyGuard: candyGuard.publicKey,
  guards: candyGuard.guards,
  groups: [
    {
      label: "early",
      guards: {
        //add other guards here
        mintLimit: some({ id: 1, limit: 5 }),
        allowList: some({ merkleRoot: getMerkleRoot(allowList) }),
        solPayment: some({ lamports: sol(1), destination: treasury }),
        startDate: some({ date: dateTime("2022-10-18T16:00:00Z") }),
        endDate: some({ date: dateTime("2022-10-18T17:00:00Z") }),
      },
    },
    {
      label: "late",
      guards: {
        solPayment: some({ lamports: sol(3), destination: treasury }),
        startDate: some({ date: dateTime("2022-10-18T17:00:00Z") }),
        botTax: some({ lamports: sol(0.001), lastInstruction: true }),
      },
    },
  ],
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);
```

*Source: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/guard-groups*